# Audit log for logins google account

Tags: google-account

Facebook provides a very useful audit log that shows login attempts made, 2 factor authentication confirmations and logins and logouts. Google's Myaccount screen shows logged in devices but does not really give a log of when logins/logouts occurred...just when the last login was. I was wondering if there is an audit log similar to that of Facebook's but for Google.

I see that for G Suite Admin's there is a way to access login audit logs (https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580120?hl=en), but is there one for google accounts that are personal (not G Suite managed).

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/notifications

Comment: admin.google.com is for G Suite account users only. You can't sign in to it using a regular Gmail account.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6076895?visit_id=637068981275460578-3733673161&p=sec_alerts&hl=en&rd=1

Comment: I was wondering if there is more detailed logs like the ones facebook provides. Those show only new logins from new locations not session updated or logins from devices that have been used before.